# Display Asp.net Core ModelState errors in javascript client

Tags: javascript, http, asp.net-core

If there is a validation error in the model.

**Server Code**

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

**Server Response:**

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-193353f9eda8d843af165acdb78f55d9-97b06892bbb3e541-00",
    "errors": {
        "ConfirmPassword": [
            "The password and confirmation password do not match."
        ]
    }
}
```

However, if we add a custom Error in server code like

```
ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

**Server Response:**

```
{
    "DuplicateUserName": [
        "User name is already taken."
    ]
}
```

1. Why is there a difference in error response?
2. How to send a similar json object response to client?
3. If its not possible then how to reconcile this at client's end?

Comment: You can refer to his artical: https://kevsoft.net/2020/02/09/adding-errors-to-model-state-and-returning-bad-request-within-asp-net-core-3-1.html

Comment: Do you know what the type is, so we can deserialise it using newtonsoft?